# completes get not called when async is false using jquery and sinon's fakeXMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, jasmine, sinon, js-test-driver

I'm using js-test-driver and inside i use jasmine for testing and sinon for spies, fakeXMLHttpRequests and so on..

Let's assume we load the following files:

```
load:
  - lib/jasmine.js
  - lib/JasmineAdapter.js
  - lib/sinon.js
  - lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
  - spec/*.js
```

Inside the spec folder is a file test.js with the following content:

```
describe('test', function() {

    it('should use sinon fakeXMLHttpRequest', function() {
        var result = [],
            requests = [];
        this.callback = function(xhr, textStatus) {
            result = textStatus;
        }
        var callbackSpy = sinon.spy(this, 'callback');
        var xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
        var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
        xhr.onCreate = function(xhr) {
            requests.push(xhr);
        }
        expect(requests.length).toBe(0);
        expect(callbackSpy.called).toBeFalsy();
        jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: 'somevalidurl.php',
            complete: this.callback
        });
        expect(requests.length).toBe(1);
        requests[0].respond(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            '[{ "id": 12, "text": "Something" }]');
        clock.tick(2000);
        expect(callbackSpy.called).toBeTruthy();
        expect(result).toBe('success')
        xhr.restore();
    });

});
```

Then we get the following errors:

```
Error: Expected false to be truthy.
Error: Expected [  ] to be 'success'.
```

If we change to "async: true" everything works fine. Is this a bug or is there some behaviour I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, my fault. for those who have the same problem:

Of course it does not work. Cause a synchronous XMLHttpRequest stops the execution. Sinon's fakeXMLHttpRequest is doing something strange in this case. So I have refactored my tested code to use asynchronous http requests.